# INotifyPropertyChange is giving Window Activation error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement and understand `INotifyProperty` Change in C# in Xamarin Forms.

Basically trying to understand the basics of Binding. I don't know why, but it is giving me a strange error:

> unable to activate window store app
>   1d51271b-455bb-47e6-a056e(some more number can't copy it)'
>   Activation request failed with Error.
>   unknown error.

Here's the code for the same

```cs
public FirstViewModel()
{

}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

string _name;
public string Name 
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
    }
}
```

Please Help.

-- i have implemented INotifyPropertyChange Interface

Comment: Could you include your `PropertyChanged` method?

Comment: The cause of the error is mostly not in the presented code, besides the implementation of `PropertyChanged` the code is fine.

Comment: Binding it to the label and Entry so that as text of Label change it Changes too. 
Binded "Name" property to the Entry and Label not  "_name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code snippets and make a common class.Just extend it , use any where in project.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace 'YourNameSpace'
{
    public class BaseNotifyPropertyChanged:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

use as:

```
        private string _checkIn;
        public string CheckIn
        {
            get { return _checkIn; }
            set
            {
                _checkIn = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CheckIn");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah it Worked.. 
Thanks Alot, 
But can someone Explain Why i Got This Problem. 
Because kind of error i Got it for the First Time.

Comment: This snippet can be improved by using the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netcore-3.1) to automatically determine the name of the attribute

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you PropertyChanged code is, but usually when triggering any event handler, especially on that may reside in another thread e.g. on the UI, you need allow for action invocation.
Try

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
```